# PostgreSQL monkey patching query execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to do something simple. I would like to print the pure sql before its execution and then to print the response when the query finishes. I think that I should monkey patch one of these two methods but the sql queries of the application do not use them.

Any idea how can I do it?

I know that it sounds stupid, but then I will extend this logic.

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
  def query(sql, name = nil) #:nodoc:
    File.open("file1", "a") { |f| f.write sql  + "\n\n" }
    log(sql, name) do
      result_as_array @connection.async_exec(sql)
      File.open("file1", "a") { |f| f.write "RESPONSE \n\n" }
    end
  end

  def execute(sql, name = nil)
    File.open("file2", "a") { |f| f.write sql + "\n\n" }
    log(sql, name) do
      @connection.async_exec(sql)
      File.open("file2", "a") { |f| f.write "RESPONSE \n\n" }
    end
  end
end
```

My main idea is to handle execution methods at least for MySQL and PostgreSQL. I found that I can do it for MySQL this way:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class Mysql2Adapter < AbstractMysqlAdapter

      def exec_query(sql, name = 'SQL', binds = [])
        File.open("path2", "a") { |f| f.write sql + "\n"  }
        result = execute(sql, name)
        ActiveRecord::Result.new(result.fields, result.to_a)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Maybe there is a way to handle this for all DB-s in one place?

Comment: it might be better to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve. have you looked at ActiveSupport::Notification maybe that is a generic point your code can hook into?

Comment: I would like to get every sql query and time needed to be executed at least for PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Comment: well yes, that sounds exactly like you should use ActiveSupport::Notification